# How to post a New Post to Google Blogger In windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps Using C# Code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I searched a lot i got the below code But Service is not available in WP8.1...What is the alternative code to Post New Posts to GoogleBlogger..

```
Service service = new Service("blogger", "exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
service.Credentials = new GDataCredentials("user@example.com", "secretPassword");
GDataGAuthRequestFactory factory = (GDataGAuthRequestFactory) service.RequestFactory;
factory.AccountType = "GOOGLE";
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you using the Blogger API v3.0 via REST requests.
Here is a nice example on how to use the WebAuthenticationBroker class to connect to OAuth 2.0 providers like Google.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122

Google Documentation on how to add a blog post.

https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#AddingAPost